# I cant get LISTAGG in Oracle to do as it should?

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

My data looks like:

```
MEDIA_ID | CHANNEL_NAME
EH/123A     CH-1
EH/123A     CH-4
EH/132A     CH-5
ES/133B     CH-1
ES/133B     CH-2
ES/133B     CH-5
```

What i want is:

```
EH/123A  |  CH-1,CH-4,CH-5
ES/123B  |  CH-1,CH-2,CH-5
```

I am using this SQL in Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
PR.MEDIA_ID
, LISTAGG(PR.CHANNEL_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHANNEL_NAME) AS PREM_CHAN
FROM PREM_REPORT PR
GROUP BY PR.MEDIA_ITEM, PR.CHANNEL_NAME;
```

What i am getting is:

```
MEDIA_ID | CHANNEL_NAME
EH/123A     CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1
EH/123A     CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4,CH-4
EH/132A     CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5
ES/133B     CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1,CH-1
ES/133B     CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2,CH-2
ES/133B     CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5,CH-5
```

Ideas?

Thanks.
Ben

Comment: remove `channel_name` from `group by`

Comment: and remove distinct. It is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT PR.MEDIA_ID,
       LISTAGG(PR.CHANNEL_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHANNEL_NAME) AS PREM_CHAN
FROM PREM_REPORT PR
GROUP BY PR.MEDIA_ITEM;
```

That is, remove `PR.CHANNEL_NAME` from your query.  I am not sure why you would get your results with the query you gave.  Perhaps there is some weird interaction between the `select distinct` and `group by`.  You almost never use `select distinct` with `group by`.

EDIT:

To return distinct values in `LIST_AGG()`, you need to use a subquery.  An easy way that works in this case is:

```
SELECT PR.MEDIA_ID,
       LISTAGG(PR.CHANNEL_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHANNEL_NAME) AS PREM_CHAN
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MEDIA_ID, CHANNEL_NAME
      FROM PREM_REPORT PR
     ) PR
GROUP BY PR.MEDIA_ITEM;
```

Comment: Thank you, do you also know how to make sure you only return Distinct values within the Listagg? 

(my data is massive, but simply put i can have duplicate rows for one reason or another)

Comment: Thank you so much, i was getting in a right muddle.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `GROUP BY` and just add `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PR.MEDIA_ID
   ,LISTAGG(PR.CHANNEL_NAME, ', ') 
   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHANNEL_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY  PR.MEDIA_ID) AS PREM_CHAN
FROM PREM_REPORT PR;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94f69/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ MEDIA_ID  ║    PREM_CHAN     ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ ES/133B   ║ CH-1, CH-2, CH-5 ║
║ EH/123A   ║ CH-1, CH-4, CH-5 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i have made a note about PARTITION. B

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the GROUP BY wrong. This is working for me.

```
WITH prem_report AS (
  SELECT 'EH/123A' media_id, 'CH-1' channel_name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'EH/123A' media_id, 'CH-4' channel_name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'EH/132A' media_id, 'CH-5' channel_name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'ES/133B' media_id, 'CH-1' channel_name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'ES/133B' media_id, 'CH-2' channel_name FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'ES/133B' media_id, 'CH-5' channel_name FROM DUAL
)
SELECT DISTINCT pr.media_id, LISTAGG(pr.channel_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP     (ORDER BY channel_name) AS prem_chan
FROM prem_report pr
GROUP BY pr.media_id
```